# pydev debug python program started by another program

Tags: pydev

I have a C++ program that starts two instances of a python program in separate processes. I have a problem in the python program which causes it to not to display any logging information. The python program instances communicate with the C++ program via Stdin and Stdout/Stderr. I want to, if possible, to run one instance of the program under the Pydev debugger since the C++ program is complaining about receiving invalid input from both of the python programs. The python program can do nothing without communication to the C++ program so running the python program in isolation does not help.

Because Stdin and Stdout are used for inter-process communication so I cannot use print() statements but must use python logging but the program seems to be crashing before anything can reach the log file. The python program was working before my last changes so the architecture is functioning OK.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for debugging the Python program launched from the C++ program would be using the remote debugger feature:

http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

(that way you can add programatically start the debugger on the python code wherever you'd like without needing to do anything special to launch it).

Comment: The problem with this is that the python code executes rapidly and probably would have terminated before I could make the connection, especially when I have a problem in the early stages of execution. But, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, the debugger would stop at the manual breakpoint you do, so, it should stop at that place, regardless of the speed of the code (unless you kill it if it takes too long).